# Updating widget from configuration activity when home key is pressed

Tags: android, configuration, widget

I am developing a widget and I am using the android:configure setting in the widget provider xml to setup the widget when first added on the home screen. The problem is that this only works if the user taps the back key from the configuration activity. If the user taps the HOME key, the widget is not added. Is there a way to add the widget on the home screen even of the user taps the Home key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround which seems to do the trick. Here is what to do:

Instead of specifying the configuration activity in the widget provider xml, specify a different activity, for example StartActivity.

In the constructor of the StartActivity do the following:

- Send a broadcast intent with its result set to RESULT_OK back to the widget
- Start the configuration activity
- Call finish to stop the StartActivity

In the onStop function of the configuration activity update the widget to reflect any changes that depend on any of the configuration settings.